# Maximum number of predictors in regression

Tags: regression, predictor

Are there any rules about the maximum number of predictors in OLS regression given the number of observations?

I was argued that I should reduce the number of predictors (20) because I have 80 observations.

Comment: OLS regression involves finding $(X^TX)^{-1}$. If $X$ is $n \times p$, $X^TX$ is $p \times p$ and for the inverse to exist $X^TX$ should be full rank. Thus, $p$ < $n$. This is just for the math to work out. In general, having 20 predictors for when you have 80 observations might seem like over fitting. But, I would need to know more about the problem.

Comment: @Greenparker What details do you need? In addition, I have performed F test to see if the reduced model gives significantly better results because I have groups of variables for which I wanted to test their contribution to the model. The reason for doing so is because it was suggested that I should eliminate individual not significant variables.

Comment: Have you performed forward/backward selection? AIC/BIC?

Comment: @Greenparker No, because I haven't heard for it until know. Is there any other way to justify the number of variables in the model and statistical insignificance of certain variables?

Comment: As you increase the number of variables in a regression model, the fit becomes better and better. This is not necessarily a good thing, since a complicated model leads to over-fitting. If you are using R, you can fit the full model with all variables, and do a backward selection. That will tell you which variables are significant, when accounting for all other variables. This is one of the easiest ways I know how.

Comment: Backward selection is basically a somewhat automated F test on many reduced models.

Comment: @Greenparker Is there a way to somehow justify the inclusion of the actual number of predictors? I have 4 samples with one sample of 80 observations and other have 120 observations.

Comment: I am not sure exactly what answer you are looking for. The way you justify the significance of a predictor to the model is by doing an F-test, and for multiple predictors, it needs to be done in a smart way, i.e., Backward or Forward selection.

Comment: @Greenparker I am looking for a credible theoretical rationale/reason to keep the variables in the model.

Comment: The credit/theoretical rationale is you consider a full model and an alternate reduced model, and test for the significance of the alternative, i.e do an F test. When the full model is large, it is impossible/waste of time to test all possible reduced models in a nested way on your own. A way around it is Backward selection, which does exactly what I wrote above in a smart way. Now, without seeing the results of the tests you have done, I can't say anything for sure. If someone is telling you to reduce the model, they might have a justifiable reason that you have not shared.

Comment: In my first comment, I had mentioned that theoretically, you should be fine putting as many at 80 predictors in the model, but practically that will probably be horrible and you will end up following the points.

Comment: @Greenparker I have been argued that I don't have enough observations per variable and that rule of thumb is 10 observations per one variable. I need to rebute this somehow. Is there any empirical evidence that it is possible to obtain reliable results with linear regression with similar observations to variables ratio?

Comment: @Greenparker Additionally, I am only using linear regression to model relationship between variables and not for prediction.

Answer (score 1):

There are no real rules to the ratio of variables to observations, as long as it is less than 1, theoretically, you should be fine. The math works out, and you get valid estimates.

What the person might be arguing about is that there are far too many variables that could not possible all be relevant in explaining the behavior of the response. Since you haven't provided the regression problem, let me give an example of my own.

Suppose you are doing a study to determine what affects the grades of high school students. You design a study where you collect over 100 predictor variables ranging from the dietary habits, ethical inclinations, family income, IQ level, gender, age, and many other things. However, you could only find 80 students to take your carefully constructed survey.

Now you have 80 observations and 100 possible indicators of why each students is different. You can't use all 100 because $p$ cannot be more than $n$ for the math to work out. Ca you use say 60? Sure! The math works, but will it make sense?

Maybe it will, but most likely it will not because for all of 60 predictors to be relevant in explaining the grades of high school students, these 80 students will have to differ in all possible combinations of these 60 predictors. That is likely not going to happen.

Where do we draw the line? There is no hard and fast line. In general it is agreed to keep a parsimonious model where there are as few predictors as needed, but not too parsimonious that you fail to capture valuable variability. To strike this balance in a theoretically valid way, selection criterions like AIC/BIC or tests of Forward/Backward selection are used.

Comment: Thank you for your time. A silly question: if a variable is categorical with 5 categories, are these counted as one or five variables?

Comment: For the purposes of estimation these are counted as 4 variables, with one being the baseline.

Comment: As with my regression problem, I am modeling the relationship between price and characteristics of a mobile phone. The characteristics I included are based on a empirical evidence dealing with a basic characteristics which fully describe a mobile phone. In these 20 variables are time dummy and brand variable (with two levels, third being the reference category).

Answer (score 1):

As you add more predictors you will find that the standard errors of your coefficients increase

```
@ARTICLE{altham84,
  author = {Altham, P M E},
  year = 1984,
  title = {Improving the precision of estimation by fitting a model},
  journal = {Journal of the Royal Statistical Society --- Series B},
  volume = 46,
  pages = {118--119},
  keywords = {glm, regression}
}
```

Before you undertake any form of selection of variables especially using an automatic procedure you might want to read

```
@article{babyak04,
   author = {Babyak, M A},
   title = {What you see may not be what you get: a brief, nontechnical
      introduction to overfitting in regression--type models},
   journal = {Psychosomatic Medicine},
   year = {2004},
   volume = {66},
   pages = {411--421},
   keywords = {glm, variable selection}
}
```

As the title promises it is a non-technical introduction.